# How to get bind Selected Item of my listview combobox's

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

Have got myself very confused on this one - apologies if the answer is really obvious but I am quite new to programming.

I have a user control set up as a view which is loaded into a content control within my main view. The datacontext for the usercontrol (Called SetView) is set in the MainView. I can happily bind to the SetView to UserControlVM (called SetVM).

In the SetVM I load in an ObservableCollection of a class I have created:

```
    public class WeightSet : Weights
{


    public string BodyArea { get; set; }
    public string ExerciseType { get; set; }
    public int SetNumber { get; set; }
    public static ObservableCollection<int> Reps { get; set; }


    #region Constructor


    //This is the main constructor
    public WeightSet(string bodyarea, string exerciseType, int setNumber)
    {
        BodyArea = bodyarea;
        ExerciseType = exerciseType;
        SetNumber = setNumber;
        Reps = new ObservableCollection<int>();
        AddReps();

    }

    #endregion Constructor

    #region Methods

    public void AddReps()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Reps.Add(i);
        }
    }
    #endregion Methods
```

My SetView then has a ListView whose ItemsSource is

```
public ObservableCollection<WeightSet> Sets
```

Here is the xaml for the ListView:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CalendarTest.SetView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:forcombo="clr-namespace:CalendarTest.Model.Repository.Local_Data"
         xmlns:VM="clr-namespace:CalendarTest.ViewModel"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="165" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid >
    <StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="{Binding CurrentExercise}" Width="100" Height="40"></Label>
        <Label Content="{Binding BodyArea}" Width="100" Height="40"></Label>

    </StackPanel>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Sets}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Set Number" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=SetNumber}" Width="100"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Select Reps" Width="120">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ComboBox Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static forcombo:WeightSet.Reps }}" ></ComboBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Reps}"></GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>


        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

When I load SetView I have my list of set numbers and a combobox with the staticlist. Here is a shot:

[image]

I cant seem to bind the selecteditem for the comboBox back to my ViewModel. Is there a way to set the selected item in the WeightSet Class? I need to be able to save the selected number?

I understand that I cant just bind to a property as the number of ComboBoxs will be decided by user? Any tips or corrections to my current design would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the `SelectedItem` property on your combobox, and add a dependencyproperty in your WeightSet class

xaml:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static forcombo:WeightSet.Reps }}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
```

and the property

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof (int), typeof (WeightSet), new PropertyMetadata(default(int)));

public int SelectedItem {
    get { return (int) GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
    set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
}
```

Then `SelectedItem` in your Sets instances will be updated when a value is selected in the combobox.

Comment: Perfect - Thanks very much exactly what I needed. Now my collection of WeightSets in my VM ends up with a Rep figure on user selection which is just what I wanted. Looks like I need to read up on Dependency Properties a bit more!!

Comment: @Luthervd: yeah, remember that you need to extend DependencyObject to be able to call the GetValue and SetValue methods. You can do this by creating a new class `WeightSetViewModel` and have that method "reflect" your `WeightSet` model class. Your view talks to the viewmodel, and the viewmodel gives the information to the model if updated. That way, you can have a bunch of "display" properties in the viewmodel as to not "pollute" your model. Write a comment if you want me to expand on the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to bind the combobox's SelectedItem dependency property to a suitable property in the view model

First off, you need to Implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx) in your Weightset class.

Next introduce a property in WeightClass called say SelectedRep which would look like

```
int _selectedRep;
///<summary>Gets or sets SelectedRep.</summary>            
public int SelectedRep
{
    get { return _selectedRep; }
    set { _selectedRep = value; OnPropertyChanged("SelectedRep"); }
}
```

Finally Modify Xaml to bind the ComboBox's SelectedItem to the SelectedRep property.

```
<ComboBox Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static forcombo:WeightSet.Reps }}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRep, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Comment: If I had just one ComboBox  would do it just like this (although I am uysing MVVM light) - however it is a user defined number of ComboBoxs so the SelectedRep needed to end up in each WeightSet Object loaded into the ViewModel